# Seamlessly Repeating a VectorLayer in OpenLayers

Tags: geojson, mapping, vector-layer, openlayers, repeating

I've created a map in VectorLayers and done a number of things like allow selection, removal of features, adjusting the view, etc. however, one thing that has me stumped is that unlike all the examples I've seen, my map doesn't repeat seamlessly along the horizontal axis.

I have a version running in code sandbox here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/seamlessly-repeating-vectorlayer-xw9fh

Note that if you click and drag the map horizontally it doesn't repeat.
Is there a property in the geojson file I should change or is it something in my setup?

I've also included my main js below:

```
import "ol/ol.css";
import Map from "ol/Map";
import VectorLayer from "ol/layer/Vector";
import VectorSource from "ol/source/Vector";
import View from "ol/View";
import GeoJSON from "ol/format/GeoJSON";

import * as worldMap from "./world.json";

var geoJSON = new GeoJSON();
var vectorFeatures = geoJSON.readFeatures(worldMap.default);
var vectorSource = new VectorSource({
  features: vectorFeatures,
  format: geoJSON
});
var vectorLayer = new VectorLayer({
  source: vectorSource
});

var map = new Map({
  target: "map",
  view: new View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 18
  })
});

// dynamically added in so it can change during runtime
map.addLayer(vectorLayer);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your features are using EPSG:4326 coordinates while your view is EPSG:3857 so the world being displayed is within 180 meters of [0, 0] (you should not need zoom 18 for a world map!).

Either transform your features to EPSG:3857 to display them

```
var vectorFeatures = geoJSON.readFeatures(worldMap.default, {
  featureProjection: "EPSG:3857"
});
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/seamlessly-repeating-vectorlayer-forked-tw1kp

or display them in an EPSG:4326 projection

```
  view: new View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 0,
    projection: "EPSG:4326"
  })
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/seamlessly-repeating-vectorlayer-forked-2ihql

Comment: Thankyou! That worked great - and it also made me realise the map shouldn't have been appearing warped!

I've now got a related issue though... Is there a way to keep that correct projection but stop it from seamlessly repeating horizontally? (I would like to give the client the option of centering the map perfectly in the frame with nothing touching the edges).

Comment: I also have another related issue that follows on but I've created a new question for that it here:
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/371686/vertically-fit-an-open-layers-map-in-a-div

Comment: Both of these issues are solved. For the one mentioned here, adding "wrapX: false" to my source layer did the trick.