# Vertically fit an Open Layers map in a div

Tags: geojson, zoom, mapping, vector-layer, openlayers

I've created an Open Layers map similar to this example I've mocked up:
https://codesandbox.io/s/seamlessly-repeating-vectorlayer-forked-igqti?file=/main.js

**[EDIT: The above link now shows a commented solution]**

The problem is, OpenLayers seems to base the minimum zoom on the width of the map - Which means if the container div is too wide, the map doesn't fit vertically and can't be zoomed out any further.

Is there a way to get around this so that my client can easily show the whole map vertically without having to constrain the horizontal width or increase the divs height?

Comment: You can override the constraint by specifying `multiWorld: true` in the view options

Comment: Thanks @Mike , that worked perfectly!
If you can post that again as an answer rather than a comment, I will mark it correct :)